# System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'XLabs.Forms.Controls.CheckBoxRenderer'

Tags: xamarin.forms, xlabs

I am trying to use XLabs.Forms.Controls.Checkbox in my Xamarin.Forms application and am running into the following error message:

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'XLabs.Forms.Controls.CheckBoxRenderer' from assembly 'XLabs.Forms.Droid, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I've tried reverting to the latest stable version (currently using the latest pre release).  I just can't seem to get beyond this one problem.  I have been able to use the control in other apps, so I don't think its an XLabs problem.  It seems that there is something wrong in my project but I cannot find it.  I have XLabs installed in both the PCL and the Droid projects.

Any suggestions as to where to look?

Update:

I had taken a working Xamarin Forms app, removed the nuget packages, changed the target to get rid of Silverlight and then reinstalled the nuget packages.  Since then, I can't get XLabs to work.  Other packages are working.  I still have a backup copy of the app (pre-retargeting) and it works fine.

Comment: In your Droid project, does your MainActivity inherit from XFormsApplicationDroid?

Comment: No, it inherits from FormsAppCompatActivity.

Comment: But, per the [XLabs documentation](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki), the MainActivity needs to inherit from XFormsApplicationDroid, right?

Comment: Why did you remove the NuGet packages initially/are you sure you added them all back? I've seen similar error messages when a NuGet package was either missing or not compatible.

Can you include the exact version numbers of the XLabs & Xamain.Forms packages you're using?

Comment: I was trying to change the PCL profile to drop Silverlight (I'm still new to all of this and I read that the latest version of XLabs didn't support it).  In order to change the profile, VS said I had to remove all nuget packages first.  So I did, however, I had installed the latest pre-release versions of Xamarin and XLabs Forms.  Since then, I created a new clean app and am noticing there may be incompatibilities.  If I kick everything back down to previous stable versions and NOT inherit from XFormsApplicationDroid, I can get it all to work again.